# Cannot display high quality pic on android app - nexus 6?

Tags: android, image

I am working on an application first in Xcode where I have a gallery that displays an image and pulls the rest of the images from online. So one image will be on the device and five or so will come from online. 
On my iPhone 5c I have no issues with this.

however doing the same thing on a friend's android Nexus 6, Whenever I come to display said image, the program lags terribly and may even stop responding / crash the app. 
The picture is 316kb andsize dimension 1775 * 2400 px.

I tried not to edit it much to not loose some of my quality but is that just to much for the nexuS? even if it is totally fine on my iPhone? 
Also I am not sure why the dimension is an issue as the resolution for that phone is 1440x2560 pixels.

Secondly I normally have issues getting images / image modes correct as I see many apps with high def images (example interface lift mobile app) but my images are somewhat poor and distorted.

So what size image and dimension would you recommend for a full screen image.

Thank you

Comment: put your images in mipmap-xxhdpi folder and test it.

Comment: ok, can you tell me why this make work?

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/getting-your-apps-ready-for-nexus-6-and.html : please go through this link

Comment: @JonSnow Thanks will do, I was also trying to read up on the folders, because when testing the app out a samsung II using the same image. There was no log / issues what so ever like I got on the nexus. So must I have two (or four) versions of a picture in each folder for a picture to show correctly?

Comment: yeah, you must have to separate the same image according to different mipmap folder structure.It just like the default app icon in different folders and device will pick the relevant sized image at run time.

Comment: @JonSnow Thanks, that sounds expensive thou. doesnt it?